# Selenium enter text to field without an identifier

Tags: selenium

I wonder if anyone know hoe to enter text into a field without any identifier. What happens is that i go to a website and are displayed a log on page in front of the web browser. If i now use F12 will I receive all the info about the page in the background except for the log in page.

Is there a way to blindly enter text, press tab, enter some more and then press enter?

Comment: What's the minus about? is there already a question like this?

Comment: Someone voted down your question as not useful, which is why it is a minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make wild guess: That log in page uses HTTP basic authentification and you need to get to that page using Selenium.

If so, simply use this:

```
 driver.get("http://username:password@your-test-site.com");
```

Where `driver` is healthy instance of `WebDriver`

**EDIT**
In my testing, I had the same issues as you are having. So try this:

1. Go to your test site manually
2. Manually log in
3. Grab the URL you have been redirected to. In my case its something like `http://my-test-site.com/faces/pages/admin/admin.xhtml`
4. Use that url to get to the site - i.e: `driver.get("http://username:password@my-test-site.com/faces/pages/admin/admin.xhtml");`

Comment: By typing "http://username:password@your-test-site.com" am I displayed the same log in window as with the regular url. Is this good or not? Still unable to find element info though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using firefox, you can take a couple of approaches:

1. Create and use a profile where you have the username and password saved.
2. Try whitelisting your domain on Firefox preferences like this:

profile.SetPreference("network.automa

```
tic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "domain.com");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://user:password@domain.com");
```